# Visual Studio Code for Linux. Working download Link

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

i want to try out the visual studio code IDE for Linux. But i can't find a working download link. The download Links on the official page seem to be broken.

Can someone provide me a working download link or something else for Linux 64bit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can literally google "visual studio code IDE for Linux" to get the right link.

Comment: that's not as easy as it seems, every article i read seems to be from 2015 and refers to the official page as a download source. But the problem is, that the official links seem to be broken.

Comment: They work for me (tried it). At the end it's https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=620884 - if the official link doesn't work, try to figure out why, or wait until it's fixed. Don't download Visual Studio from 3rd party which may be compromised, or bundling their own malware with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can literally google "visual studio code IDE for Linux" to get the right link

Answer (score 0):

Did you see on their website ? [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download)

Comment: As you can see, i wrote : "The download links on the official page seem to be broken."